# WHM/Cpanel - Reopen closed upgrade database page

Tags: mysql, cpanel, mariadb, whm

Today I decide to migrate from MySQL MariaDB. For this I used the guide from WHM panel and choose interactive upgrate. All was goo till I closed the page and now I can't see the status of process and I cannot interact with him.

Is there any chance to reopen this session?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Solved by self. When the upgrade process reach step 5, a new link button to upgrade process is available.